# Error failure AH01075 on IBM Bluemix PHP instance

Tags: php, ibm-cloud

I have a `PHP instance on IBM Bluemix` installed.

Sometimes I get the error message:

> [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 46:tid 140596635207424] (70007)The timeout
>   specified has expired: [client 159.***.***.***:55528] AH01075: Error
>   dispatching request to : (polling)

I this error occurs, the `php` page within the instance won’t response any more.

I use a standard `php` instance from `IBM Bluemix`.
What can cause this error and can this be solved by changing a `apache` of `php` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have to increase TimeOut in apache configuration, or, if you'd like to have a proxy-specific timeout set ProxyTimeout.

In your local source code you have to create a folder called ".bp-config" like this to set httpd configuration parameters

```
.bp-config/httpd/extra/httpd-php.conf
```

and re-push your application on bluemix environment

```
> cf push your_app_name
```

In this case this link could be useful for you: https://serverfault.com/questions/500467/apache2-proxy-timeout

You should also try with another custom buildpack (heroku php buildpack for eample):

```
> cf push your_app_name -b https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php.git
```